# FontFamily not applying to arabic text imported from google fonts

Tags: android, fonts, textview

So I tried multiple fonts that are Arabic fonts found on fonts.google.com and were added via android studio, but don't take any affect on the text views in my app. The English fonts on the other hand work perfectly. I also tried importing my own font from a file that didn't work either. Any ideas?

[image]

The XML For Arabic textview

```
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/card_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fontFamily="@font/cairo_bold"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textDirection="rtl"
    android:textSize="26sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

As for English textview

```
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:fontFamily="@font/quicksand"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="@string/player_header"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="14sp" />
```

Comment: change your emulators language English to Arabic

Comment: I want it to work on all devices not just my emulator

Comment: have you added Arabic string in your file ?

Comment: did you tried it in real device..??

Comment: @MilanPansuriya The arabic text is obtained from a JSON request and placed in the text view.

Comment: @ALTegani Yes ofcourse on the emulator and my actual Samsung Galaxy J5 device, Oh and also the tablet

Comment: Do you have an [mcve] for people to look at?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans done

Comment: google webfonts are optimised-for-web, not system fonts, so it's not super surprising that they don't work correctly in an app rather than on a web page. Did you try wit a full version of Roboto (which has arabic support) to see if it's the type(s) of font(s) you're currently using?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Epic fail. tried the full version of Roboto too :(

Comment: Epic fail doesn't tell people anything, unfortunately. How are you debugging? In a [mcve], do the adb logs show anything around the font that is active, and what happens when it's asked to style Arabic text?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans you see I found a solution to do this programatically load a font, it worked but since it's a recyclerview it takes time to set the font for every text view.

Comment: That is information you should put in your post, not mention in passing in a comment =)